# Is SQL Server Express DB replacement for SQL Server CE Compact Edition?

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-express, localdb

SQL Server CE Compact Edition has officially passed the extended end support date:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-sql-server-compact-40

is SQL Server Express LocalDB a replacement for this?   We have a windows app with a database and have used CE for years. This document says LocalDB targeted for developers:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15

If I want to have a file based is SQLite a better option?  Or use the full SQL Server Express instead of LocalDB?

Thank you

Comment: It depends. Don't use LocalDB! Consider Express, but it requires admin access to the PC.

Comment: thank you.  it's just overkill for a simple windows app, so...